# Pytest is not applying Django's migrations

Tags: django, pytest, django-migrations, pytest-django

I'm setting up for an existing Django + postgresql project that uses pytest to run the tests (alongisde the pytest-django library).

The exact error I'm getting is `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_site" does not exist`, and this happens any time I run the test suite. The reason this fails is because the test framework is creating a test database and applying migrations (seemingly) in the wrong order (or just not all of them): There's a custom model that requires the `django_site` table, but the migration that creates that table is not recognized/applied in order.

Perhaps it's import to note that the `django_site` model has its migrations overridden.

I don't know exactly what to make of this, as I have a local postgres database for development purposes that had no problem applying all migrations.

Any idea as to why this might happen?

Comment: I had a similar problem that was caused by one of the latest migrations deleting a proxy model, where there were previous migrations setting permissions for that model. Because a proxy model only lives in your codebase, it cannot find it even before running the migration. Not sure if this can help you out, but seeing your question was not answered I hope it is a useful breadcrumb (should you not have solved it already)

Comment: I think I overcame the problem already but, unfortunately, I didn't remember I had posted the question so I didn't answer it; and now I don't remember how I resolved it 

Comment: It happened to me when I forgot to create the migration in the first place. I lived with the impression it was there, but it wasn't. So yeah, pay attention to that.

Comment: This could be related: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/986